# Protractor interctive mode strange error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

from time to time I have such kind of but.

```
✗ node node_modules/protractor/bin/elementexplorer.js https://www.studytube-staging.nl/login
Type <tab> to see a list of locator strategies.
Use the `list` helper function to find elements by strategy:
  e.g., list(by.binding('')) gets all bindings.

Getting page at: https://www.studytube-staging.nl/login
> element
There was a webdriver error: TypeError Object function (locator) {
    return new ElementArrayFinder().all(locator).toElementFinder_();
  } has no method 'then'
```

don't know what to do with it, please help.

**UPD**: discussion on protractor project issues page - https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1514

Comment: I built an improved element explorer called elementor. You may want to take a look: https://www.npmjs.org/package/elementor Feedback is welcome.

Comment: nice! I'll definitely have a look